# Get country name from title column and add them in new coulmn

Tags: python, python-3.x

Want to get country name from the title column and add list of them in new column.

```
import pycountry
text = df[title]
for country in pycountry.countries:
    if country.name in text:
        print(country.name)
```

**Data Frame:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function with the for loop you have, then use a lambda on the dataframe to create a new column.

```
def get_country(text):
  countries = []
  for country in pycountry.countries:
    if country.name in text:
      countries.append(country.name)
  return countries

df["country"] = df["title"].apply(lambda x: get_country(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But Stored only single country, For Title: India to make US vaccines with Japan funds, Australia logistics, store only Australia.

Comment: I've edited my answer - create an empty list and append countries as you find them.